# How do I inherit the custom date format of Field1 when Field1 is called as part of an Expression built for Field2 within a Table?

Tags: vba, ms-access

Field0 is "RecordID" and is an AutoNumber.
Field1 is "IssueDate" which is selected from calendar and is formatted as yymmdd.
Field2 is "LotNumber" which is built as an expression: "ED" & [IssueDate] & "TF" & [RecordID].

I want the output in Field2 to be "EDyymmddTF#", but instead I get "EDmm/dd/yyyyTF#"

Please help!
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As LotNumber is a derived field, there should be no need to actually store it in the database. You can create it by using the following:

```
="ED" & Format([IssueDate],"yymmdd") & "TF" & [RecordID]
```

Regards,